# How to test react useContext useReducer dispatch in component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, dispatch, use-context

hope someone can point me the right direction with this.  Basically I've created a react app which makes use of hooks, specifically useContext, useEffect and useReducer.  My problem is that I can't seem to get tests to detect click or dispatch events of the related component.

Stripped down version of my app can be found at : https://github.com/atlantisstorm/hooks-testing
Tests relate to layout.test.js script.

I've tried various approaches, different ways of mocking dispatch, useContext, etc but no joy with it.  Most recent version.

layout.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Layout from './layout';
import App from './app';
import { Provider, initialState } from './context';

const dispatch = jest.fn();

const spy = jest
  .spyOn(React, 'useContext')
  .mockImplementation(() => ({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: dispatch
}));

describe('Layout component', () => {
  it('starts with a count of 0', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <App>
        <Provider>
          <Layout />
        </Provider>
      </App>
    );

    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    const refreshButton = getByTestId('fetch-button');

    fireEvent.click(refreshButton);

    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });
});
```

layout.jsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Context } from "./context";

const Layout = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Context);
  const { displayThings, things } = state;

  const onClickDisplay = (event) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    event.preventDefault;
    dispatch({ type: "DISPLAY_THINGS" });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_THINGS" });
  }, [displayThings]);

  const btnText = displayThings ? "hide things" : "display things";
  return (
    <div>
        <button data-testid="fetch-button" onClick={onClickDisplay}>{btnText}</button>
        { displayThings ? 
            <p>We got some things!</p>
          :
            <p>No things to show!</p>
        }
        { displayThings && things.map((thing) =>
            <p>{ thing }</p>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Provider from "./context";
import Layout from './layout';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Layout />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

context.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { reducer } from "./reducer";

export const Context = createContext();

export const initialState = {
  displayThings: false,
  things: []
};

export const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Provider;
```

reducer.jsx

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DISPLAY_THINGS": {
      const displayThings = state.displayThings ? false : true; 
      return { ...state, displayThings };
    }

    case "FETCH_THINGS": {
      const things = state.displayThings ? [
          "thing one",
          "thing two"            
      ] : [];
      return { ...state, things };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

I'm sure the answer will be easy when I see it, but just trying to figure out I can detect the click event plus detect the 'dispatch' events?   (I've already got separate test in the main app to properly test dispatch response/actions)

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
Ok, I think I've got a reasonable, though not perfect, solution.  First I just added optional testDispatch and testState props to the context.jsx module.

**new context.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { reducer } from "./reducer";

export const Context = createContext();

export const initialState = {
  displayThings: false,
  things: []
};

export const Provider = ({ children, testDispatch, testState }) => {
  const [iState, iDispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const dispatch = testDispatch ? testDispatch : iDispatch;
  const state = testState ? testState : iState;
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Provider;
```

Then in layout.test.jsx I just simply pass in mocked jest dispatch function plus state as necessary.  Also removed the outer App wrapping as that seemed to prevent the props from being passed through.

**new layout.test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Layout from './layout';
import { Provider } from './context';

describe('Layout component', () => {
  it('starts with a count of 0', () => {
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    const state = {
      displayThings: false,
      things: []
    };
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <Provider testDispatch={dispatch} testState={state}>
        <Layout />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, { type: "FETCH_THINGS" });

    const refreshButton = getByTestId('fetch-things-button');
    fireEvent.click(refreshButton);

    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    // Important: The order of the calls should be this, but dispatch is reporting them 
    // the opposite way around in the this test, i.e. FETCH_THINGS, then DISPLAY_THINGS... 
    //expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, { type: "DISPLAY_THINGS" });
    //expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, { type: "FETCH_THINGS" });
   
    // ... so as dispatch behaves correctly outside of testing for the moment I'm just settling for
    // knowing that dispatch was at least called twice with the correct parameters.
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: "DISPLAY_THINGS" });
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: "FETCH_THINGS" });

  });
});
```

One little caveat though, as noted above, when the 'fetch-things-button' was fired, it reported the dispatch in the wrong order. :/ So I just settled for knowing the correct calls where triggered, but if anyone knows why the call order isn't as expected I would be pleased to know.

https://github.com/atlantisstorm/hooks-testing update to reflect the above if anyone is interested.

Comment: any update this question?

Comment: you should start testing UI interaction and outcome rather than implementation itself. that's the correct approach to use react-testing-library

Answer (score 9):

A few months back I was also trying to write unit tests for reducer + context for an app. So, here's my solution to test useReducer and useContext.

**FeaturesProvider.js**

```
    import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

    import { featuresInitialState, featuresReducer } from '../reducers/featuresReducer';

    export const FeatureContext = createContext();

    const FeaturesProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(featuresReducer, featuresInitialState);

      return <FeatureContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</FeatureContext.Provider>;
    };

    export const useFeature = () => useContext(FeatureContext);

    export default FeaturesProvider;
```

**FeaturesProvider.test.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
    import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
    import FeaturesProvider, { useFeature, FeatureContext } from './FeaturesProvider';

    const state = { features: [] };
    const dispatch = jest.fn();

    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
      <FeatureContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
        {children}
      </FeatureContext.Provider>
    );

    const mockUseContext = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ state, dispatch }));

    React.useContext = mockUseContext;

    describe('useFeature test', () => {
      test('should return present feature toggles  with its state and dispatch function', () => {
        render(<FeaturesProvider />);
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useFeature(), { wrapper });

        expect(result.current.state.features.length).toBe(0);
        expect(result.current).toEqual({ state, dispatch });
      });
    });
```

**featuresReducer.js**

```
    import ApplicationConfig from '../config/app-config';
    import actions from './actions';

    export const featuresInitialState = {
      features: [],
      environments: ApplicationConfig.ENVIRONMENTS,
      toastMessage: null
    };

    const { INITIALIZE_DATA, TOGGLE_FEATURE, ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST } = actions;

    export const featuresReducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
      switch (type) {
        case INITIALIZE_DATA:
          return {
            ...state,
            [payload.name]: payload.data
          };

        case TOGGLE_FEATURE:
          return {
            ...state,
            features: state.features.map((feature) => (feature.featureToggleName === payload.featureToggleName
              ? {
                ...feature,
                environmentState:
                  { ...feature.environmentState, [payload.environment]: !feature.environmentState[payload.environment] }
              }
              : feature))
          };

        case ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST:
          return { ...state, toastMessage: payload.message };

        default:
          return { ...state };
      }
    };
```

**featuresReducer.test.js**

```
import { featuresReducer } from './featuresReducer';
import actions from './actions';

const { INITIALIZE_DATA, TOGGLE_FEATURE, ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST } = actions;

describe('Reducer function test', () => {
  test('should initialize data when INITIALIZE_DATA action is dispatched', () => {
    const featuresState = {
      features: []
    };

    const action = {
      type: INITIALIZE_DATA,
      payload: {
        name: 'features',
        data: [{
          featureId: '23456', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: true, replica: true, prod: false }
        }]
      }
    };

    const updatedState = featuresReducer(featuresState, action);

    expect(updatedState).toEqual({
      features: [{
        featureId: '23456', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: true, replica: true, prod: false }
      }]
    });
  });

  test('should toggle the feature for the given feature and environemt when TOGGLE_FEATURE action is disptched', () => {
    const featuresState = {
      features: [{
        featureId: '23456', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: true, replica: true, prod: false }
      }, {
        featureId: '23458', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23458_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: true, replica: true, prod: false }
      }]
    };

    const action = {
      type: TOGGLE_FEATURE,
      payload: { featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environment: 'sit' }
    };

    const updatedState = featuresReducer(featuresState, action);

    expect(updatedState).toEqual({
      features: [{
        featureId: '23456', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: false, replica: true, prod: false }
      }, {
        featureId: '23458', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23458_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: true, replica: true, prod: false }
      }]
    });
  });

  test('should enable the toast message when ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST action is dispatched with the message as part of payload', () => {
    const featuresState = {
      toastMessage: null
    };

    const action = {
      type: ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST,
      payload: { message: 'Something went wrong!' }
    };

    const updatedState = featuresReducer(featuresState, action);

    expect(updatedState).toEqual({ toastMessage: 'Something went wrong!' });
  });

  test('should disable the toast message when ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST action is dispatched with message as null as part of payload', () => {
    const featuresState = {
      toastMessage: null
    };

    const action = {
      type: ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_TOAST,
      payload: { message: null }
    };

    const updatedState = featuresReducer(featuresState, action);

    expect(updatedState).toEqual({ toastMessage: null });
  });

  test('should return the current state when the action with no specific type is dispatched', () => {
    const featuresState = {
      features: [{
        featureId: '23456', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: false, replica: true, prod: false }
      }]
    };

    const action = {};

    const updatedState = featuresReducer(featuresState, action);

    expect(updatedState).toEqual({
      features: [{
        featureId: '23456', featureName: 'WO photo download', featureToggleName: '23456_WOPhotoDownload', environmentState: { sit: false, replica: true, prod: false }
      }]
    });
  });
});
```